# using an update trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

I have been trying to use an update trigger which checks for the title_id in the primary table. This is what i did:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[EX6] on [dbo].[sales]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
BEGIN 
   IF EXISTS(SELECT S.title_id 
             FROM inserted S
             INNER JOIN Titles T On T.title_id = S.title_id)
   BEGIN 
      UPDATE Sales 
      SET sales.stor_id = inserted.stor_id
         , sales.ord_num = inserted.ord_num
         , sales.title_id = inserted.title_id
          , sales.ord_order = inserted.ord_order,
         ,sales.qty = inserted.qty
   END
```

However,  when i execute this, I am getting the following errors:

```
     the multi-part identifier inserted.stor_id could not be bound
```

The same error occurs for the rest of the columns used in update command. So, can u please help me out in solving this and successfully update the column in the database..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have aliased inserted to be `S` so you will need to continue that in your `UPDATE` statement

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[EX6] on [dbo].[sales]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
BEGIN 
   IF EXISTS(SELECT S.title_id 
             FROM inserted S
             INNER JOIN Titles T On T.title_id = S.title_id)
   BEGIN 
      UPDATE st
      SET st.stor_id = S.stor_id
         , st.ord_num = S.ord_num
         , st.title_id = S.title_id
         , st.ord_order = S.ord_order
         , st.qty = S.qty
      FROM Sales AS st
      INNER JOIN inserted S ON st.stor_id = S.stor_id
   END
```

I have updated the answer to reflect changes discussed in chat.

Comment: Sorry, didn't look closely enough the first time.  I've updated my query.  You need to join the inserted (and probably Titles) tables into you update statement to bring in the data

Comment: I am confused how it would be the same error. My code does not have `inserted.stor_id` anywhere, so I would expect the error to be different.

Comment: sorry now sales.stor_id could not be bound

Comment: That makes sense, please see my updated answer, put aliases where they belong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4963/discussion-between-adam-wenger-and-user838359)